# Windows 7 WebDAV network drive size shows local drive size. Does not let me copy files

Tags: windows-7, webdav, quota, network-drive

When I map a WebDAV drive as a network drive in Windows 7 (Using the `Map Network Drive` option in Explorer), the mapped drive size is shown as exactly what my C: drive size is. e.g. my C: drive is 40GB with 2GB free. My network drive is 200 GB and empty. But explorer shows my network drive as 40GB with 2GB free. When I try to copy a file size larger than 2GB, it does not let me do it.

I am asking this question on StackOverflow, because I am developing this WebDAV server. I am using the open source Java based [Milton](http://milton.io) framework. I modified it to send the `quota-available-bytes` and `quota-used-bytes`. However, Windows is still showing the size incorrectly. Please not that Finder in OS X is able to show the correct drive size, so I don't think this is an issue with the server.

A google search reveals that this is a known Windows issue. Is there a workaround for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2386902), it is by design, not a known Windows issue.

*"This is by design. A WebDAV mapped drive's capacity is set to match the client machine's System drive capacity. This means that the capacity you get from a WebDAV mapped drive is the same as your local System drive. System drive is where Windows is installed."*